# How to test a remote UDP Port

Tags: c#, .net, windows, udp

I am looking for a simple way to see if a remote UDP port is open on a server

Comment: possible duplicate of [UDP port open check C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879605/udp-port-open-check-c-sharp)

Comment: @Joe that question is definitely something different... the method in that answer does NOT apply to remote serverrs only to the local machine !

Comment: udp doesn't send the AWK response that tcp/ip does...there has to be an initial handshake in there somewhere. try sending the port some data and see what happens.

Comment: Connect the socket to the target and send more than one datagram to it. If you don't get any exceptions either the port is closed at the firewall or there is something bound to it in the host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*BEWARE that several firewalls/network setups/IDS etc. might influence the result... the following method is NOT 100% reliable but it is the only method possible with UDP IMHO (since UDP is connectionless).*

You can use [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx), [set a receive timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) on the underlying [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.client.aspx), [make a connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.connect.aspx) to that remote server/port, [`Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k.aspx) some small message (`byte[]` !) and call [`Receive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx).

IF the port is closed you get an exception saying that the connection was forcibly closed (`SocketException` with `ErrorCode` 10054 = `WSAECONNRESET`)... which means the port is NOT open.

Otherwise you either receive an answer OR a timeout exception - both should be interpreted as "the UDP port is open".

Comment: @ralu I know it is reddiculous but that's how that exception is actually phrased...

Comment: I am sure it is, but is still funny. UdpClient is than application protocol over UDP?

Comment: @ralu `UdpClient` is a built-in class which makes a nice wrapper around Socket for UDP handling...

Comment: @ralu added the exact WinSocket Error code (10054) which is available in the Exception for that case...

Comment: @Yahia Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing, but in my case, I always receive a SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut for closed ports(or inexisting hosts). Is there a workaround?

Comment: @J4N inexisting hosts is something different from a closed port... there is NO 100% way to remotely diagnose UDP ports... what exactly is your goal ?

Comment: @Yahia: We are developing an application(composed of client and servers), and most of our customers have routers that doesn't allow ICMP(ping). The idea was then to check if we have one of our service running on the remote machine. Unfortunately, we can't add a method on service since we have a lot of different service type.

Comment: @Yahia Most are using TCP, some are using UDP(for large set of data)

Comment: @J4N you situation seems a bit complicated... I would create 1 "central management service" where all services actively register themselves when they start, send "heartbeats" and unregister when they shutdown...

Comment: I tried it on everything in my lan and i always get a Timeout, whether the port is open or not. too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. That is by design because UDP is connectionless. You have to solve that on application layer.

Comment: You can, and you can't 'solve that on application layer'.

Comment: is it true? can you give link for this reference?