# UdpClient not failing when endpoint is unavailable

Tags: c#, udpclient

It was my expectation that, if the endpoint is not available, the `UdpClient.Connect()` method would throw an exception that I could capture and, say, alter a label's text to say if the program was connected to the server or not. However, despite me having turned off the server that I'm trying to connect to, the method completes with no issue. Is there some way to resolve this issue, or some other method I should be attempting?

My current code (IP address blanked out, but is valid):

```
UdpClient chatConnection = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"), 1000);

// Initialize client/server connection and set status text
try
{
    chatConnection.Connect(serverEndPoint);
    SL_Status.Text = "Connected";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SL_Status.Text = "Not Connected";
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server. See console for logs.");
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UDP is connectionless checking if client is connected doesn't apply to it.
There is however a workaround that in some cases may work:
[answer by Yahia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265669/how-to-test-a-remote-udp-port)

Comment: Ahh, perfect, thank you! I knew UDP was more lax with its connection rules, didn't know that it was near-on useless trying to use the `Connect()` method for it haha