# How to get all server which listening UDP port xxxx in Windows Phone 8 Project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, udp

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879681/360094
he use this code

```
int myport = 7525;
bool alreadyinuse = (from p in System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners() where p.Port == myport select p).Count() == 1;
```

I cannot find it in Windows Phone 8 project.
[image]

Comment: I looking for IPGlobalProperties but it not in the list I've shown

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 uses a subset of the .NET 4.5 framework, so not everything is available.